# How can I make regex not accept some values?

Tags: python, regex

I want my regex to match some values, but not accept others. The base regex is `^/.+/.+$`

I want to not accept questions mark in the last `/` part, and not accept `people` or `dungen` as the first `/` part.

```
MATCH: /a/b/c/d
MATCH: /a/b
NO MATCH: /people/b/c/d
MATCH: /peoples/b/c/d
NO MATCH: /a/b/c?x=y
```

I know you can use `[^ABCD]` in order to NOT match characters, but it won't work with whole strings.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rejecting question marks after the last `/` is easy - use a character class `[^?]` instead of `.`:

```
^/.+/[^?]+$
```

To reject `people` or `dungen` in between the two `/`s, you can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Since you want to reject `/people/` but accept `/peoples/` the lookahead looks all the way to the end of the string.

```
^/(?!(?:people|dungen)/.+$).+/.+$
```

So combining the two:

```
^/(?!(?:people|dungen)/[^?]+$).+/[^?]+$
```

Let's test.

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'^/(?!(?:people|dungen)/[^?]+$).+/[^?]+$')
>>> for s in ['/a/b/c/d', '/a/b', '/people/b/c/d', '/peoples/b/c/d', '/a/b/c?x=y']:
...     print not not r.search(s)
...
True
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^/(?!(people|dungen)/).+/[^?]+$
```